# Bind Textbox in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

My View

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.PartView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:EComponents.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="PartUc"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:PartViewModel}">        
        <Grid>
            <TextBox x:Name="NameTb" Text="{Binding Name}" />
       </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My ViewModel

```
public class PartViewModel : ViewModel<Part>
{
    public PartViewModel(Part model) : base(model)
    {
        PartListViewModel.OnSelectedPartChanged += PartListViewModel_OnSelectedPartChanged;
    }    
    void PartListViewModel_OnSelectedPartChanged(Part p)
    {
        Model = Part.GetPart(p);
    }      
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return Model.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Name != value)
            {
                Model.Name = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

My Model

```
public class Part
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know why but the TextBox in my UserControl does not get filled with the Name property of my part even though this line is called

```
Model = Part.GetPart(p);
```

I set the DataContent of my View like this

```
public partial class PartView : UserControl
{
    public PartView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new PartViewModel(new Part());
    }
}
```

Comment: If the problem occurs at runtime where/how do you set `DataContext` of `PartView` to `PartViewModel`?

Comment: It occurs at runtime and I set it in my code behind the View ´DataContext = new PartViewModel(new Part());`

Comment: try calling `this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");`, or maybe even `this.OnPropertyChanged(null);`, after `Model = Part.GetPart(p);`. I'm guessing you don't notify UI when `Model` is changed

Comment: @dkozl: I swear I tried that before :) That is it. Now it works. If you put that in a short answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is seems as if you don't notify UI when `Model` is changed in `PartListViewModel_OnSelectedPartChanged`. You need to call `this.OnPropertyChanged(...)` for every `Model` related property after it's changed or call it with null argument `this.OnPropertyChanged(null)` to refresh all properties

```
void PartListViewModel_OnSelectedPartChanged(Part p)
{
    Model = Part.GetPart(p);
    this.OnPropertyChanged(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a slight issue in your code:

```
        if (Name != value)
        {
            Model.Name = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
```

Should be:

```
        if (Model.Name != value)
        {
            Model.Name = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
```

Self-referencing the Name property of your view model will give you issues.

Last but not least you need code in your code-behind to bind the DataContext at runtime.

**Edit**

I just took a look at your code again as well as the comments on the question. When you set the value of Model in the event handler, you need to set DataContext there as well. Changing the model reference doesn't update the DataContext.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But it still does not not update the textbox